# Convert buffer data to byte[] in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, typescript, byte

I'm trying to convert a buffer data from fingerprint capture to byte[]. Here's what i've tried

```
 ipcMain.on('captureFingerprint', (event, arg) => {
  test({
    event_handler: (data, cb) => {
      console.log('Received event', data);
      fs.readFile(data, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data)
        var binaryImage = new Blob([data])
        event.sender.send('requestReceived', binaryImage);
      })
      cb();
    }
  }, );
});
```

Unfortunately it's not working. What i'm i missing?

Comment: `Buffer` instances [are already `Uint8Array` instances](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray), so your commented-out `var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data)` would work but may not even be necessary. It sounds like `event.sender.send` (or whatever's receiving it at the other end) isn't expecting what you think it's expecting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm expecting an output in the name of an arg. I've successfully converted the buffer data to base 64 encoded string but it appears i need the format in a byte[]

Comment: Nothing in the code above converts to a base-64 string. You've said you need `byte[]`, which in JavaScript is `Uint8Array`. See my comment above again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Kindly see below for converting same to base64 string                                                                                                                                `ipcMain.on('captureFingerprint', (event, arg) => {
  test({
    event_handler: (data, cb) => {
      let buffImg = Buffer.from(data);
      fs.readFile(buffImg.toString(), function(err, data) {
        var base64Image = new Buffer(buffImg).toString('base64');
        event.sender.send('requestReceived', base64Image);
      });
      cb();
    }
  }, );
});`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm still stucked. Any ideas please

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually got it to work using **Uint8Array** but this time i set `byteArr = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(data))`. Thanks a lot. Appreciate

Comment: I'm glad it's working! But that's very odd, because [`fs.readFile` returns a `Buffer` when you don't specify an encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) (and your code doesn't specify an encoding). So `Buffer.from(data)` shouldn't be necessary.